# How to use Laravel Pagination with models relationsips?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have categories and items tables. Each item belongs to only one category and each category has many items. So, in Category model I defined this relationship:

```
public function items()
{ return $this->hasMany('Item', 'catid'); }
```

and I retrieve data for a category this way:

```
$category = Category::find($id);
return View::make('admin.categories.catdetails')->with('category', $category);
```

and in my view I can loop through data:

```
 @foreach ($category->items as $item)
        <tr>          
            <td> {{ $item->name }}  </td> 
            <td> {{number_format($item->price, 2, '.', '')}} </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

but this results in all items in on page. How to make use of laravel pagination in case that I have so many items for one page??
How can I use

```
::paginate() // in controller or model
->links() // in view
```

as, so far, it throws many errors and I can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `paginate()` on the relationship object, which you access by `->items()` (not `->items`)

```
$items = $category->items()->paginate(10);

return View::make('admin.categories.catdetails')
    ->with('category', $category)
    ->with('items', $items);
```

Then in your view:

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
```

And:

```
$items->links()
```

---

You could use an attribute accessor to achieve what you want. In your model:

```
public function getPaginatedItemsAttribute(){
    return $this->items()->paginate(10);
}
```

And then you use it like this:

```
@foreach ($category->paginatedItems as $item)
```

And:

```
$category->paginatedItems->links()
```

Comment: thanks. but I'm asking if we can do it without sending 2 different variables (category and items) . Is there any solution??

Comment: Well yes and no. You can do it but you would have to create a variable like `<?php $items = $category->items()->paginate(10); ?>` and I don't see how that would be better than passing it from the controller.

Comment: I tried to make pagination at the model it self. `public function items()
{ return $this->hasMany('Item', 'catid')->paginate(10); }` , but it fails.

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer. (The difference between the attribute accessor and just calling `->items()->paginate(10)->links()` is that this caches the result so the query is only run once)

Comment: Hey. `public function items() { return $this->hasMany('Item', 'catid')->paginate(10); }` works just fine. It it should be called as a function, `$category->items()`

Comment: Yes. But that triggers two query calls one when you access the results and another one when you get the `links()` and it makes your relationship unusable for everything else

Comment: I will, as soon as you tell me the advantage over the attribute accessor way I suggested.

Comment: could u, plz, help me with this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547080/how-to-debug-laravel-5-projects]

Comment: How can someone use the callback function if we want different results from the `items` relation?