# How to debug Laravel 5 projects?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I ran command

```
php artisan optimize
```

and changed debug settings in app.php file to be

```
'debug' => 'true',
```

and added 'everyone' to have full access over 'storage' folder. I don't know what else I can do to let debugger work in my Laravel 5 project.
I'm stuck with 'Whoops, looks like something went wrong' message.
Any Ideas??

Comment: Can you do `dd(config('app.debug'))` somewhere? The result should be `true`

Comment: do u have any idea how to grant write permissions to web server over storage folder??

Comment: I hardly think that's the problem since you are getting the error in your log file aren't you?

Comment: yes. I have log file filled with errors.

Comment: Then this has nothing to do with the storage folder. Do you have this problem for all kind of errors? (To check try to access a non-existing URL that should throw a 404 exception)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71044/discussion-between-dr-maf-and-lukasgeiter).

Comment: Add flip/whoops to your composer file.
Check this modified version of laravel which has whoops integrated in it:
https://github.com/kheshav/laravel5-flip-whoops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving is a general error, likely server-side configuration.  Without any information on your setup it will be pretty hard to determine what your issue is.  Based upon your question and comments to others responses I have a couple of things for you.

1. You stated "I don't know what else I can do to let debugger work in my Laravel 5 project".  Laravel 5 doesn't have a native debugger any more which I imagine is why your page just shows "Whoops, looks like something went wrong".  Your statement would indicate that you have a debugger, so which are you trying to use, or was that statement incorrect?
2. You stated that you changed the debug settings the app.php file.  Is there a reason why you changed this in app.php?  The debug setting by default is `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG')` which is sufficient in most cases.  You should have a .env file in the root of your project (created automatically if you did a composer create-project, if not you need to copy .env.example to .env on your own).  The .env file will enable debug for you as there is a line that states APP_DEBUG=true.
3. Jesse Schutt gave great information in his response above (which I recommend upvoting), including a link to a debug bar that is compatible with L5.  Yet again you are stating that you are satisfied with your error stack which implies that you actually have one.  If you were satisfied with it, you would have no need to have posted here as you would already have more information on your error.  If you are assuming that the filp/whoops is in l5 still and that's what you want you'll have to re-enable it.  Follow the instructions at http://mattstauffer.co/blog/bringing-whoops-back-to-laravel-5

Answer (score 3):

The `debug => true` will just show you the full error stack when you hit an error with your app. It doesn't give metrics and statistics. If you are looking for that kind of information check out the article here:

https://laravel-news.com/2015/02/laravel-debugbar/

Comment: Sir, I'm satisfied with this error stack. But I can't get it. Do u have any idea about how getting it work??

Comment: You mean you can't get it to display even if there is an error in your app?

Comment: yes. I'm stuck with `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.` message.

Comment: Got it. What environment are you in? Look in your .env file at the root of your project and see if there is a debug configuration or an environment declaration.

Comment: first 2 lines are `APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true`

Comment: And what is debug set to in app.php?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71042/discussion-between-jesse-schutt-and-dr-maf).